# Intuition behind monodromy group.

Tags: complex-analysis

What is a monodromy group from an intuitive standpoint with respect to the roots of a polynomial, or even branch points of a complex function? I realize this question was asked in a slightly different context [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683054/understanding-monodromy-by-examples) (in the context of topology). But I would like to understand this in the light of complex variables. Thanks!